# Node.js Bookshelf.js Knex relation issue

Tags: node.js, express, knex.js, bookshelf.js

I'm really lost and would love some help, this is confusing the crap out of me.

My database structure is as follows:

> table -> user ( has a role_id )
>
> table -> roles ( has role_id, role_name )

Based on the user's role_id I want to authenticate with a role_id.

Here's my route:

```
router.get('/.isadmin', jwtAuth, authorizedRoles('admin'), function(req, res) {
    const { id, orgId, role_id } = req.user.attributes;
    res.json({
        success: true,
        id,
        orgId,
        roleId: role_id
    })
});
```

Here's my strategy:

```
passport.use(new JwtStrategy(opts, function(jwt_payload, done) {
    // User.where('id', jwt_payload.id).fetch({withRelated: 'roles'})
    console.log('jwt_payload', jwt_payload)
        User.where('id', jwt_payload.id).fetch({withRelated: 'roles'})
        .then(user => user ? done(null, user) : done(null, false))
        .catch(err => done(err, false));
}));
```

Here's my user model:

```
const Role = require('./role');
module.exports = bookshelf.Model.extend({
    tableName: 'user',
    roles() {
        return this.hasMany(Role, 'role_id')
    },
```

Here's my role model:

```
module.exports = bookshelf.Model.extend({
    tableName: 'roles'
});
```

Here's my authorizedRoles() function ( this is not done ). The problem I have is that I want to be able to pass in authorizedRoles('admin') and logically if the authenticated user has role_id = 2 it should match with the table -> roles entry with role_id = 2 & match with role_name = "admin"

```
module.exports = function(...authorizedRoles) {
    return function (req, res, next) {

        const user = req.user.attributes;
        const currentUserRole = req.user.attributes.role_id;
        const validRoles = req.roles;

        // const currentUserRoles = validRoles.find(currentUserRole);
        const test = req.user.related('roles');

        const currentUserRoles = req.user.related('roles').models.map(role => {
            debugger;
            // return role.attributes.role_id === currentUserRole;
            return role.attributes.role_id
        });

        if (!_.intersection(currentUserRoles, authorizedRoles).length) {
            res.status(403);
            res.send('Not permitted');
            return;
        }
        next();
    }
};
```

To my issue:

```
req.user.related('roles').models.map(role => {
```

There's only one role being returned, which matches with the ID of the user in the user table with the role_id in the table roles. It should match with the **table(users)** *role_id* -> **table(roles)** *role_id*

Comment: Try using `fetchAll` instead of `fetch` while fetching the user to get all roles. Also, correct syntax for `withRelated` is `{withRelated: ['roles']}`

Comment: @HarshalGangurde Didn't make any difference. It seems like "return this.hasMany(Role, 'role_id')" matches role_id with the user_id, but I want to return all roles. How would I do that?

Comment: When you fetch role related to the user it should return only single instance as expected because each user has a single `role_id`. To actually implement `hasMany` relation you should be storing `user_id` in roles table, then when you fetch `user` you can also fetch all roles which have `user_id = user.id`. Not an ideal solution though. Not sure what you are exactly trying to do but you can fetch all roles separately before fetching user.

Comment: I've read your description and still don't understand what you're getting and what you were expecting to get. Can you clarify that with actual examples?